# Data extrapoliation, how to remove nonsense data?

Tags: matlab, extrapolation

Consider some data in the following form

```
Sample = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
Data = [10 10 10 10 8 5 2 1 0.6 0.4]';
```

Now I know for a fact this data should form a straight line when plotted with a semilog axis:

[image: example plot]

The problem is sample no. 1, 2, 3 and 4 all max out at 10 due to a limitation of an instrument used. So what I would like to do is fit a straight line to samples 5:10, and then use that to extrapolate back so I can estimate the values of 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I am confused as to how to do this in MATLAB, my attempt is as follows:

```
Sample = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
Data = [10 10 10 10 8 5 2 1 0.6 0.4]';

Sample(1:4) = [];
Data(1:4) = [];

x = Sample;
y = Data;

p = polyfit(x,y,0);
x1 = Sample;
f1 = polyval(p,x1);

figure;
semilogy(Sample,Data,'ro');
hold on
plot(x1,f1,'b--')
```

which produces this plot...

[image: plot2]

Comment: `p = polyfit(x,y,0);` gives only a constant. Need `p = polyfit(x,y,1);` to actually fit a line of a form y = ax+b.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. When I change it to 1, I obtain a fitted blue line that is not straight though, so I am rather confused. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fitting a straight line to exponential data, hence you must apply the `polyfit` on the logarithm of that data. Then apply `exp()` on the result of polyval. In the end, also use `semilogy()` to add the line to the semilogy plot.
Also I removed unneeded variables. I keep it so that you see all of the Data/Sample values, but the fit ignores the first 4 values, as you desired.

```
Sample = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]';
Data = [10 10 10 10 8 5 2 1 0.6 0.4]';

% // Data for fit: indx 5 to end
x = Sample(5:end);
y = Data(5:end);

p = polyfit(x,log(y),1); % // fit of logarithmic data
f1 = exp(polyval(p,x)); % // apply exp() function

figure;
semilogy(Sample,Data,'ro');
hold on
semilogy(x,f1,'b--') % // also semilogy!
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

If you dont want to plot the original data, then just use

```
figure;
semilogy(x,y,'ro');
hold on
semilogy(x,f1,'b--') % // also semilogy!
```

instead.

Comment: Incredible, Thanks so much. I competently missed that I was plotting semilogy not plot(x,log(y)). Thanks